# How to make a multiple asynchronous calls using .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

The scenario is that an ASP.NET webforms page will call a web service in an async manner to make about 8 web service calls to various providers for data. I would like to run them in parallel to speed things up.
I also need to wait for them all to come back before moving on.

What is the best way to achieve this?  Please provide some code examples (I'm from VB).

Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh... ASP.Net MVC Has even better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For ASP.Net MVC...**

Use an [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.aspx)

- [Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC (with examples)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx)

**For good ole webforms...**

If you are using .Net 4 you might consider the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).  Otherwise you may need to just use the [Async Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)

- [Task Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)
- [Async Pattern to Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28printer%29.aspx)

Comment: The TPL is very complex.  I don't have time to create an example right now.  I'm sure you can find good examples on MSDN and Stackoverflow.